# XFetchName always returns 0

Tags: c, linux, xlib

im trying to write a C code to get the title of the Active Window in my Linux System, but the Function XFetchName always returnes zero, i also tried XGetWMName, same result...
but using xprop, i can see that there is a string in the "WM_NAME" property

can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code?

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>


int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
      Display *display;
      Window focus;
      char *window_name;
      int revert;

      display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
      XGetInputFocus(display, &focus, &revert);
      int ret = XFetchName(display, focus, &window_name);
      printf("ret = %d\n", ret);
      if (window_name) printf("Title = %s\n", window_name);
      return 0;
}
```

thanks.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine on the machine I'm currently using (OSX Lion) when run from an Xterm (which by default has the name `xterm` set). In addition, I added a call to `XStoreName()` to set it to something else first and that worked as expected as well with your code retrieving the new name just fine. This is of course after renaming `_main()` to `main()` - How are you running your program?

Comment: the '_' is just to define an entry point name with the command line "-Wl,-e__main" because im not using stdlib, i dont think this has to do anything. and still when executed from Ubuntu's Terminal it returns 0, but works from xterm, is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 7):

You can try using [`XGetWMName`](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ICC/client-to-window-manager/XGetWMName.html) function. Although the discriptions of [`XGetWMName`](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ICC/client-to-window-manager/XGetWMName.html) and [`XFetchName`](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ICC/client-to-window-manager/XFetchName.html) both say they will return the `WM_NAME` property, it seems that they are different from each other. Some times, they return the same name. Some times, only `XGetWMName` returns the name.

You can also use `xwininfo -root -tree` to get all the windows' name, and compare with the result of `XFetchName` and `XGetWMName`.

This code can list all the windows and print the window id and result of `XFetchName` and `XGetWMName`. You can use the window id to look up in the output of `xwininfo -root -tree`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

void enum_windows(Display* display, Window window, int depth) {
  int i;

  XTextProperty text;
  XGetWMName(display, window, &text);
  char* name;
  XFetchName(display, window, &name);
  for (i = 0; i < depth; i++)
    printf("\t");
  printf("id=0x%x, XFetchName=\"%s\", XGetWMName=\"%s\"\n", window, name != NULL ? name : "(no name)", text.value);

  Window root, parent;
  Window* children;
  int n;
  XQueryTree(display, window, &root, &parent, &children, &n);
  if (children != NULL) {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      enum_windows(display, children[i], depth + 1);
    }
    XFree(children);
  }
}

int main() {
  Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
  Window root = XDefaultRootWindow(display);
  enum_windows(display, root, 0);
}
```

Here's a piece of output showing that the result of two functions may be different.

```
id=0x2c7, XFetchName="(no name)", XGetWMName="(null)"
    id=0x400001, XFetchName="(no name)", XGetWMName="(null)"
    id=0x800036, XFetchName="(no name)", XGetWMName="(null)"
        id=0x1400001, XFetchName="(no name)", XGetWMName="c - XFetchName always returns 0 - Stack Overflow - Chromium"
    id=0x1000001, XFetchName="terminator", XGetWMName="terminator"
        id=0x1000002, XFetchName="(no name)", XGetWMName="(null)"
    id=0x1200001, XFetchName="chromium", XGetWMName="chromium"
        id=0x1200002, XFetchName="(no name)", XGetWMName="(null)"
```

Here's a piece of the output of `xwininfo -root -tree` showing the name of these windows.
xwininfo: Window id: 0x2c7 (the root window) (has no name)

```
  Root window id: 0x2c7 (the root window) (has no name)
  Parent window id: 0x0 (none)
     29 children:
     0x1200001 "chromium": ("chromium" "Chromium")  10x10+10+10  +10+10
        1 child:
        0x1200002 (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +9+9
     0x1000001 "terminator": ("terminator" "Terminator")  10x10+10+10  +10+10
        1 child:
        0x1000002 (has no name): ()  1x1+-1+-1  +9+9
     0x800036 (has no name): ()  1364x741+0+25  +0+25
        1 child:
        0x1400001 "c - XFetchName always returns 0 - Stack Overflow - Chromium": ("Chromium" "Chromium")  1364x741+0+0  +1+26
     0x400001 (has no name): ()  10x10+-20+-20  +-20+-20
```

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 /*
  * The following functions are internationalized substitutions
  * for XFetchName and XGetIconName using XGetWMName and
  * XGetWMIconName.  
  *
  * Please note that the third arguments have to be freed using free(), 
  * not XFree().
  */
 Status
 I18N_FetchName(dpy, w, winname)
     Display *dpy;
     Window w;
     char ** winname;
 {
     int    status;
     XTextProperty text_prop;
     char **list;
     int    num;

     status = XGetWMName(dpy, w, &text_prop);
     if (!status || !text_prop.value || !text_prop.nitems) return 0;
     status = XmbTextPropertyToTextList(dpy, &text_prop, &list, &num);
     if (status < Success || !num || !*list) return 0;
     XFree(text_prop.value);
     *winname = (char *)strdup(*list);
     XFreeStringList(list);
     return 1;
 }
```

//XFetchName uses XGetWMName

see: [enter link description here](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/intro-i18n/ch-examples.en.html)

Answer (score -1):

The `XFetchName` function returns the name of the specified window. If it succeeds, it returns a nonzero status; otherwise, no name has been set for the window, and it returns zero.

You need to set a name for your window.

I started an `xterm` session and executed you code and got the following output:

```
sangeeth@home:~/work/test$ ./a.out 
ret = 1 
Title = sangeeth@home: ~/work/test
sangeeth@home:~/work/test$
```

OTOH, I tried compiling your program and got the following error:

```
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
```

You need to change

```
int _main( int argc, char* argv[] )
```

to

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Comment: I suspect the `_main()` is because it's a hook into a larger framework which could be the actual problem.

Comment: @BrianRoach Thats a good point. We need to hear more details from the OP.

Comment: the '_' is just to define an entry point name "-Wl,-e__main" because im not using stdlib

Comment: well, it works when executed under xterm, but not when executed from normal terminal !

Comment: Perhaps the "normal terminal" is only setting the modern _NET_WM_NAME and not the older WM_NAME?   http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#id2506989