# XLIB C - get window by PID

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I begin with xlib and I would like to know if it is possible with xlib in C to "catch" a window with its PID for be able to move the window, resize it...?

For example ask my program the width and height of firefox's window. I do not know if my question is clearer.

Thank you

Comment: It looks that you want to code your Window Manager from scratch. How many years of full time work can you afford spending?

Comment: Looks a bit like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). What exactly do you want to achieve? So far, your comments are confusing. And you should *edit your question* to improve it (not explain it partly in comments to e.g. my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you mean the process-id of the (Linux or POSIX) client owning the window.

But your question has no real sense: the X client could be on some operating system without process-ids, or it could be running on a *remote* machine (different of the one running the X11 server), e.g. with `ssh -X` (and then you cannot do much with that pid). Be sure to understand more about the [X Window System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) (and the roles of client, server, window manager).

However, you could study (with pain and care) [X11 Window protocols and architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_protocols_and_architecture) (include [X11 core protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_core_protocol)),  the [EWMH](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html) specifications (and also [ICCCM](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/specs/ICCCM/icccm.html)). Look into [`_NET_WM_PID`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm140200472565744) & [XGetWMClientMachine](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/ICC/client-to-session-manager/XGetWMClientMachine.html)

<sup>(Xlib & all the [X protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_protocols_and_architecture) are really *complex*; you would need to read thousands of pages to understand all of them; in 2017 that effort might be obsolete, e.g. because of [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_%28display_server_protocol%29); it is preferable to use some higher-level toolkit like [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [GTK](http://gtk.org/)).</sup>

If you want to write some [X window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_window_manager) (they are complex beasts, because conventions related to X have become very complex), consider studying the source code of some existing one and adapt it to your needs....

Comment: I begin in this domain, so I do not really know how all of it works. I would like be able with my program to get information of others windows. For example ask my program the width and height of firefox's window. I do not know if my question is clearer. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @wammder: that motivation should go into your question, not as a comment to my answer. So please *edit your question*

Comment: It looks like you want to code some *compliant* window manager from scratch. How many years can you afford for this task? By the time you'll have something usable, X11 might have become obsolete... Several Linux distributions are switching to Wayland...

Comment: Done. Sorry. I want to do it because I want to develop a VNC server, and without the xlib I don't know how I can access to the framebuffer of an other window.

Comment: Then I still recommend starting from the code of some *existing* VNC server, or leveraging above some *existing* X toolkit (and/or some window manager). Life is short. Your project could take you a dozen of years of full-time work. Can you afford that much time?

Comment: No I have not so much time. So if I understand well, with the xlib it is hard and take long time to get information from others windows, and I have to look for another library ?

Comment: You need first to read a lot (in particular study the X11 protocol, the Xlib, EWMH, ICCCM; and reading all that can take months). Then you could decide what to do (and on what existing software can you leverage). Your current goals look very confusing. BTW, X11 is less sexy today than ten years ago (and Wayland could replace X11 in a few years)

Comment: Why do you need to know the pid to get information from other windows?  X clients usually do this with window ids and client ids, not process ids.

Answer (score 1):

You could [iterate through all windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825661/xfetchname-always-returns-0) and search for the program that you want by it's name. Afterwards you could use [XMoveResizeWindow](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xmoveresizewindow) to move and resize as you please.