# Haskell fetchName from X11 library does not return the name of the window

Tags: c, linux, haskell, x11, xlib

Having the following Haskell code:

```
import           Control.Concurrent
import           Data.Time.Clock
import           Debug.Trace
import           Graphics.X11
import           Graphics.X11.Xlib.Extras

main :: IO ()
main = do
  d <- openDisplay ""
  loop d

loop :: Display -> IO ()
loop d = do
  time <- getCurrentTime
  (w, _) <- getInputFocus d
  maybeName <- fetchName d w
  windowAttrs <- getWindowAttributes d w
  print $ show time ++ " Name: " ++ show maybeName ++ " Width: " ++ show (wa_width windowAttrs)
  threadDelay 1000000
  loop d
```

The window title returned by [fetchName](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/X11-1.8/docs/Graphics-X11-Xlib-Extras.html#v:fetchName) is always `Nothing`.

Haskell [X11](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/X11-1.8) library is a wrapper around [Xlib](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/)

Possibly related issues:

- The width of the window is either correct or it has the value `1`.
- [XFetchName always returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8825661/750216)

Comment: I'd guess that `w` is the input focus window, which is typically a sub-sub-sub...window of the one you want, e.g. it is a single text entry widget. Perhaps you could try to access the parent, then the grandparent, and so on until you find a window having a title.

Comment: @chi You are most probably right about that. The irony is that all the programs I was testing against did not have a title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `fetchName` isn't always filled in. Instead you need to use the `_NET_WM_NAME` property:

```
import           Control.Concurrent
import           Data.Time.Clock
import           Debug.Trace
import           Graphics.X11
import           Graphics.X11.Xlib.Extras

main :: IO ()
main = do
  d <- openDisplay ""
  loop d

loop :: Display -> IO ()
loop d = do
  time <- getCurrentTime
  (w, _) <- getInputFocus d
  a <- internAtom d "_NET_WM_NAME" False
  p <- getTextProperty d w a
  ps <- wcTextPropertyToTextList d p
  windowAttrs <- getWindowAttributes d w
  print $ show time ++ " Name: " ++ show ps ++ " Width: " ++ show (wa_width windowAttrs)
  threadDelay 1000000
  loop d
```

This is what XMonad does:

https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/8b055621e92e7ade127043e968f50713c15a00a0/src/XMonad/ManageHook.hs#L71-L80

Answer (score 1):

In the end I had to adapt Brian's answer to the more complete definition from XMonad (because of exceptions being thrown by some windows):

```
import           Control.Exception.Extensible          (SomeException (..),
                                                        bracket)
import qualified Control.Exception.Extensible          as E
import           Graphics.X11
import           Graphics.X11.Xlib.Extras

getWindowTitle :: Display -> IO String
getWindowTitle d = do
  (w, _) <- getInputFocus d
  let getProp =
          (internAtom d "_NET_WM_NAME" False >>= getTextProperty d w)
              `E.catch` \(SomeException _) -> getTextProperty d w wM_NAME
      extract prop = do l <- wcTextPropertyToTextList d prop
                        return $ if null l then "" else head l
  bracket getProp (xFree . tp_value) extract `E.catch` \(SomeException _) -> return ""
```